# What is wrong with this msgbox code? (VB)

Tags: vb.net, messagebox

edit: Don't worry, i made a silly mistake, I had 3 characters instead of 4

```
   MessageBox.Show("Well done you completed the game in " & (Label4.Text.Substring(0, 2)) & ":" & (Label4.Text.Substring(2, 2)) & " milliseconds. Well Done!")
```

So why doesn't it work? If it helps, here is the error code:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Index and length must refer to a location within the string."

Comment: CAPITAL words / sentences convey the meaning as shouting. If you want to edit the description, just include the word 'Edit:' at the end of the description with your new details. The way its done now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you tell me what exactly the 'Label4' contains, I know it has numbers, but what other text. Sorry for doing this as an answer but the 'Comment' button isn't anywhere on the page.

Comment: label 4 contains 4 numbers (e.g. 3428)

Comment: And you want to achieve something like this?: Prompts saying: "Well done  you completed the game in 3428 milliseconds. Well Done!"  ?

Comment: ITS FIXED, i had 3 numbers, just need a code to search for if there are 3 numbers or 4 because it changes

Comment: Instead of substring why dont you just do this?: MessageBox.Show("Well done you completed the game in " & Label4.Text & ": milliseconds. Well Done!")

Answer (score 2):

I would suspect that your `Label4.Text` property is shorter than you've requested.

Comment: label4.text is 4 letters long

Answer (score 1):

I realize you have already accepted an answer but I am responding to your comment that you want it to display in seconds. Try something like this:

```
Dim result As Integer

If Integer.TryParse(Label4.text, result) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Well done you completed the game in " & (result / 1000).ToString & " seconds. Well Done!")
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Well done you completed the game in null seconds. Well Done!")
End If
```